# Load Error persists with 'require watir-webdriver'

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm trying to use the Watir gem in a short ruby script. When I run the script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new

browser.goto 'http://wers.tunegenie.com/'

puts browser.div(class: 'song')
```

I get a load error:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)   from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'

I've followed troubleshooting questions in other posts (need to install web-driver gem, need to require rubygems) but no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that `watir-webdriver` is installed?  Do you see it when you run `gem list`?

Answer (score 3):

Try to isolate your script/project into its own folder, create your Gemfile and replace the require to `watir` as the doc. says

In your folder, run `bundle init` to create your Gemfile. Add the watir gem (`gem 'watir'`), and replace your script to:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://wers.tunegenie.com/'

puts browser.div(class: 'song')
```